# Record movie using Sony API

Tags: sony-camera-api

I am using a RX100III in a remote aplication using the API and updated the firmware just last week.

But only shootmode available is still. If I select in the camera the film mode. In that case the shootmode "movie" can be selected and the movierecord works; but in other modes only still.

But if I use the movie button in the camera it works in all modes. I look in the documentation but I can not find how to select the mode in the camera to start movie record.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're developping your owne application, you can use "getAvailableShootMode" to check for available modes.

Also, check if your model need to call the "startRecMode" function first! (I dont know about the RX100III). The documentation says: Some camera models need "startRecMode" API call before accessing camera settings. See "startRecMode" for details.

Then, use "setShootMode" method to set the mode you want! As described in the documentation:

```
"method": "setShootMode", "params": ["movie"]
```

Comment: My camera needs  startRecMode  and I am using  ; but when  I try to select   {
"method": "setShootMode",
"params": ["movie"],
"id": 1,
"version": "1.0"
}   the answer is   {
 "id": 1,
 "error": [
  500,
  "Set operation failed."
 ]
}    I apreciate any indication to search

Comment: Assuming you do have now both modes (still and movie) available! You can check the Camera status using "getEvent" to make sure it's not busy; if the status is IDLE, then call "setShootMode". I suggest you keep the physical button on the movie mode since that helps the camera to work in all modes!